# Sacks property for higher cardinals

Tags: set-theory, forcing

It is well known, that the Sacks forcing has the property that for any $f: \omega \rightarrow \omega$ in generic extension, one can obtain $F:\omega \rightarrow [\omega]^{<\omega}$ in ground model, such that some condition forces $f(n)\in F(n)$ for all $n$. 
 Is there any non-trivial forcing notion, which has this property for $f:\omega_2\rightarrow \omega$ instead? If we had $f:\omega_2 \rightarrow \omega_2$, and required $F:\omega_2 \rightarrow [\omega_2]^{<\omega_2}$, then probably generalization of Sacks forcing considered by Kanamori would work (http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/f.pdf). But it is important for me to have $F:\omega_2 \rightarrow [\omega]^{<\omega}$. Is there any hope for such forcing? ;)

Comment: You seem to be missing a subscript in the last $[\omega]^{<\omega}$.

Comment: Do you know if this is possible with $\omega_1$ in place of $\omega_2$?

Comment: I don't know if this works for $\omega_1$. This is also a meaningful question.
@AsafKaragila No, this is ok. This is supposed to be a "longer" version of Sacks property.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that a gap this large would be hard to have. Recall Kurepa's theorem: If $T$ is a tree of height $\kappa$ with each level of size $<\lambda$, where $\lambda^+\leq\kappa$, then $T$ has a branch. Something tells me that this $F$ thing you wrote there can be somehow translated to a statement about trees of height $\omega_2$ with width $\leq\aleph_0$, which are without branches, which is impossible. But what do I know about the Sacks property? Practically nothing.